# Cloud service for periodic worker-task invocation

Tags: cloud, worker, webhooks, periodic-task

We have a standard web role running on Azure. At this stage, all of our "background" tasks are handled by webhooks (e.g. our payment gateway notifies us when a customer's credit card is about to expire).

That said, we will soon have the need to delegate certain "non-webhookable" tasks (e.g. sending emails) to a "worker" mechanism.

We have the option of deploying a worker role to Azure. One disadvantage here is that we have to run another role instance, which will cost us more money.

So, my question is: is there some cloud service that is potentially cheaper than Azure, reliable and can issue a GET request to a public URL on a periodic basis?

Aside from sites like Pingdom (which is more for uptime monitoring), I haven't come across any solutions of this type. Does this mean I'm missing something important in my thinking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use an extra small worker role. Currently it costs just ~14 USD per month. One instance would be enough for most simple tasks. You could feed tasks to it via Azure Storage Queue. This would help with load leveling and making sure tasks are not lost in case of downtime or some temporary failure.

Alternatively, Azure has a built in scheduler that can invoke your specified URLs or post messages to Azure Storage Queue.

Comment: I guess I should have looked into the pricing a bit more...I wasn't aware that the extra small instance was that cheap. Thanks :).